# counting the value of specifi column in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that keeps a use reputation point as

```
id | bronze_badge | gold_badge | reputation_points | user_id
1 | 1            | 1          | 300               | 3
2 | 13           | 3          | 22                | 1
3 | 4            | 1          | 10                | 22
4 | 0            | 21         | 52                | 3
```

Now, I would like to display the numbers of gold bages a user_id 3 has which is `22` i.e. `1 + 21`

so, currently, I am doing it as

```
   $gold =  "SELECT gold_badge FROM user where user id = 3";
   $gold =   $db->query($gold);
   ...
```

and then I am doing a foreach loop to count the gold_bages, surely there must be a better way to do this with `count()` I tried using `count()`, but it only counts the number of rows, and not the gold_bages.

Comment: To add up the numbers, use `SUM()`, not `COUNT()`. If that's the goal.

Comment: yeah...select sum(gold_badge) from user where user_id = 3

Comment: Thanks guys. Are you sure no one wants some reps?

Comment: You're welcome, it's your choice ;-) and it has been done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add up the numbers, use `SUM()`, not `COUNT()`.

Consult http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sum/

As  Randyka (Yudhistira) also stated in a comment

```
select sum(gold_badge) from user where user_id = 3
```

- Kudos to Randyka for that.

See the list of MySQL aggregate functions:

- http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx